# Unrecognized Input for LESS

Tags: css, indexing, less

```
@grayBorderColor: lightgrey;
@blueBorderColor: lightskyblue;

.eaSqm-filters-header {
    margin: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    &-title {
        display: none;
    }
    &-config {
        float: bottom;
        &-expandable-exitFullIcon {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    &-panel {
        &-downArrowIcon {
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
            display: none;
        }
        &-upArrowIcon {
            height: 32px;
            width: 32px;
        }
    }
}

.eaSqm-filters-Location {
    margin: 6px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.eaSqm-filters-Customer {
    margin: 6px;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}

.eaSqm-filters-Component {
    margin: 6px;
    height: 400px;
    display: none;
}
```

When I tried to run the files, it say that there's an unrecognized error for the above file at 1,56, and am not sure what kind of an error it is. I have corrected the missing braces and tried to fix the internal colors, but I still keep getting the error, and am unable to figure out the error's cause.

Comment: As a couple of others have pointed out, you are missing a closing brace but that wouldn't/shouldn't result in *Unrecognized input*. It will most probably say *missing losing }*. The error that you are getting should be due to some other part of your code. Please add the full code into the question.

Comment: Perhaps include your LESS into an online compiler and check for errors. http://winless.org/online-less-compiler

Comment: The updated code compiles perfectly fine at http://lesstester.com/. There were **no errors**.

Comment: But i was unable to build it , it say unrecognized input.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a curly brace at the end `}` of the structure, which means you're not closing the `.eaSqm-filters-header`.

**Solution**

```
@grayBorderColor:lightgrey;
@blueBorderColor: lightskyblue;

.eaSqm-filters-header {
    margin: 6px;
    &-title {
      display: none;
    }

    &-config {
      float: bottom;
      &-expandable-exitFullIcon {
        display: none;
    }
} /* Added missing curly brace */
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `}` < this is not a semi-colon?? this is a semi-colon `;`

Comment: `}` it's a curly brace